# How to debug python wheel build on macos remote server (azure pipelines)

Tags: python, macos, debugging, azure-pipelines

I try to build wheel for `imagecodecs` python package. Previous version I build without any problem.
For current revision I got wheels for linux (`manylinux2010`) and macos, but without openmp support.

I would like to build also with openmp support. For this purpose I use `gcc` from `brew`.

From previous version of `imagecodecs` to dependency there is added `snappy`, `zopflipy` and changed version of `jxrlib`.

I use `cibuildweel` to build wheel so it is build with python installed from official `pkg` files.
Build pass, then when test start it fail with (on azure pipelines)

`python(53258,0x7fffa20fb380) malloc: *** error for object 0x109c85c00: pointer being freed was not allocated`

When I download it on my computer whole test set pass.

On azure pipelines there is no option to login on machine. I try to debug it with
`lldb --batch -o "br set -n malloc_error_break" -o "run" -o "bt" -o "c" -- python -m pytest {project}/tests/`

Then I got:

```
+ lldb --batch -o "br set -n malloc_error_break" -o "run" -o "bt" -o "c" -- python -m pytest /Users/runner/runners/2.163.1/work/1/s/tests/
(lldb) target create "python"
Current executable set to 'python' (x86_64).
(lldb) settings set -- target.run-args  "-m" "pytest" "/Users/runner/runners/2.163.1/work/1/s/tests/"
(lldb) br set -n malloc_error_break
Breakpoint 1: where = libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_error_break, address = 0x00000000000119e6
(lldb) run
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.17, pytest-4.6.8, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1
python(53294,0x7fff97d45380) malloc: *** error for object 0x10fc3ec00: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Process 53294 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5f7d89e6 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_error_break
libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_error_break:
->  0x7fff5f7d89e6 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
    0x7fff5f7d89e7 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x7fff5f7d89ea <+4>: nop    
    0x7fff5f7d89eb <+5>: nopl   (%rax)
Target 0: (python) stopped.

Process 53294 launched: '/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/tmp_g9gpq37/bin/python' (x86_64)
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff5f7d89e6 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_error_break
    frame #1: 0x00007fff5f7ca82d libsystem_malloc.dylib`free + 400
    frame #2: 0x000000010face5bd libstdc++.6.dylib`std::locale::_Impl::~_Impl() + 109
    frame #3: 0x00007fff97d24998 libsystem_c.dylib`__stdinp + 8
(lldb) c
```

Whole code is here https://github.com/Czaki/imagecodecs/tree/2019.12.16

Pipelines are here https://dev.azure.com/bokota/open%20source%20contrib/_build?definitionId=3&_a=summary

Any idea how I can debug this? How to find where pointer is created?

---

EDIT
In this case problem is connected with compiling `zopflipy` with `gcc-9`/`g++-9`. I need to compile test dependencies with `clang`

Answer (score 1):

You can check **Enable system diagnostics** to get verbose logs when you **Run pipeline**.

You can also click add variable to **add a variable** named `system.debug` and set its value to `true`. Please refer to [troubleshoot build and release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#configure-verbose-logs).

If you would like to login on the agent machine. You can configure your [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops), which will allow you to login and troubleshoot your builds.

Comment: The `system.debug` do not change anything. I have only access to one macos machine and on it everything works well.    

Everything look like one thread try to free variable before it is allocated. But I do not know how to debug it properly. Debugger do not show enough information (whole stacktrace is in system lib) and there is no option for interactive work.

Comment: You can check the c++ compiler version of your local macos and specify to use the same version in your build pipeline yml. It said in [this thread](https://github.com/YasserAsmi/jvar/issues/21) that the error could be fixed by changing the version of compiler

Comment: Problem is that I download wheel build on azure pipeline and launch it on my local machine. And it works. Problem occurs during run tests for this wheel on azure pipeline machine.

Comment: The main difference is that on machine I use python from brew and on azure pipelines python form pkg (official installer) is used